# Named_scope with lambda rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lambda

I need to refactor it to rails 4 style

model name `Invoice`

I have

```
 named_scope :with_name_like, lambda { |name|
     name.blank? ? {} : { :conditions => ['LOWER(name) LIKE ?', "%#{name.downcase}%"], :joins => :client }
   }
```

I did

```
  def self.with_name_like
    ->(name){where('LOWER(name) LIKE ?', "%#{name.downcase}%").joins(:client)}
  end
```

but getting

```
 Invoice.with_name_like
 => #<Proc:0x00000004f35d50@/home/stasyan/current/app/models/invoice.rb:23 (lambda)>
```

How to put ternary operator to this method? with lambda?

and how to do it to latest syntax

```
named_scope :ordered, :order => "date DESC"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `all`:

```
scope :with_name_like, ->(name) {
  name.blank? ? all : where('LOWER(name) LIKE ?', "%#{name.downcase}%").joins(:client)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
def self.with_name_like(name)
  if name
    where('LOWER(name) LIKE ?', "%#{name.downcase}%").joins(:client)
  else
    self
  end
end
```

I prefer class method over parameterized scope definition.